# Spreadsheets.values.batchClear throws 'Requested entity was not found' in the shared spreadsheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, add-on

I've a public editor addon which runs the following code to clear cell values. It is being called using `google.script.run` from the sidebar. It's **working fine** for the **spreadsheets that are not shared**:

**Google App Script**

```
function clearCells(){
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
 const dataToClear = {ranges:['Sheet1!A1']};
 Sheets.Spreadsheets?.Values?.batchClear(dataToClear, spreadsheetId);
}
```

**Sidebar(javascript function)**

```
function clearCells(){
  google.script.run.clearCells();
}
```

The same code throws the following exception in case of **shared spreadsheet**.

> { [GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchClear failed with error: Requested entity was not found.]
> name: 'GoogleJsonResponseException',
> details: { message: 'Requested entity was not found.', code: 404 } }

I tried to run the above code **as macro on the shared spreadsheet** and it worked fine (surprise).

Not sure why it fails for Editor Addon.

**Edits**

I am not logged into multiple accounts in the same browser, so App script is executed by a single account only. Hence the question is not duplicate.

**---Issue is with the scope----**

Scopes used

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly

When I change the scopes to the following, it starts working:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I am not sure why it's throwing **'Requested entity was not found'** error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I was trying to test the same code by creating a new sheet and share it with some people, however this work for me every time and I was unable to reproduce the error. Are you able to reproduce it from your end in a new sheet?

Comment: @FernandoLara, is it working for the shared user?. I am calling the above code (function) using google.script.run from html page. have you done the same?

Comment: Does the user that you shared the spreadsheet with has editor access to the sheet?

Comment: Yes, they do have.